# Cant hit Node-Red web page on Vultr Machine

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, node-red, vultr

I have just finished setting up Node-red on the a cloud machine hosted with vultr ( Ubuntu 20.04 x64 ) and I am wanting to be able to hit the Node-Red web page but I am failing to do so.

I have setup WireGuard so I can VPN into the machine

[image: hostname -i]

I am able to ping the servers Local IP address from my Windows PC[image: Windows PC]

But I am still unable to hit the Node-Red  Web Page[image: Web Page]

Even though Node-Red is running[image: running]

I am fairly new to working with cloud machines so any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you haven't opened port 1880 for the server.

This could be in one of 2 places

1. Vultr appear to have their own firewall which you will need to ensure a suitable rule to allow TCP traffice on port 1880 exists. How to configure the firewall appears to be documented here https://www.vultr.com/docs/vultr-firewall-quickstart-guide/
2. You will need to make sure that the port is open in the Ubuntu Firewall as well. Running `sudo ufw allow 1880/tcp` should do this.

Comment: This seems to do the trick, thanks for your reply.